# Unsupported Android Plugin version: 3.5.4

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Starting this morning, my flutter app build on android is failing with

```
Unsupported Android Plugin version: 3.5.4.
```

To be clear, it has been building fine for months. No changes to build files only the code. And suddenly this error appears.

Anyone know why and have any solutions?

Solutions tried:

- Updating gradle to 4.1.0, results in `flutter build apk` no longer building the apk, or, if it does, `url_launcher` starts throwing `MissingPluginException`.
- Run `flutter clean` and `flutter pub cache repair`

Answer (score 0):

It's known that if you upgraded your Flutter version to 2.5.0 and if an error ocurred during upgrade could lead to some dependencies deleted. (Many of my friends and I had suffered from this bug). If that it's not your case, try to invalidate cache and restart or re-download the dependencies from the Internet. Or upgrade the gradle and the flutter version.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to specify a download path for Gradle to download that version.
there is a file called "gradle-wrapper.properties" inside android/gradle/wrapper directory try to change "distributionUrl" to an existed source like this

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.9.1-all.zip
```

Also, you can find all available versions from this [list](https://services.gradle.org/distributions/)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, the fix was to specify the flavor in the build command.

Answer (score -1):

If you encounter such an error in your project, what fixed it for me was changing `jcenter()` to `mavenCentral()` in `android/build.gradle`

```
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
```

---

After believing this was the solution, the release build starting failing again with the same error. I managed to nail it down to in the `android/app/build.gradle`

```
    buildTypes {
        release {
            ...
            debuggable true // this was causing the error
            ...
        }
    }
```

Link to [Git Issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/90814)